# What is a "sling belay?"

Tags: rock-climbing

Rock climbing topos have various standardized symbols, such as xx for a bolt anchor, or a dashed line for face climbing. In keys of symbols, I've sometimes seen SB defined as a "sling belay." What does this mean? Does it mean that there is a natural feature that you can throw a cordelette around and use as an anchor?

Comment: Could you maybe add a picture of a topo that uses the term? I haven't encountered it personally.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The glossary section of *Big Walls* by John Long and John Middendorf defines a sling belay as:

> A hanging belay with no stance; listed as SB on topos

From perusing forums, I suspect this term arose during the golden age of Yosemite climbing, but was soon subsumed by the term "hanging belay".  A Google Ngrams comparison gives a good visual of this.

[image: Google Ngrams chart showing "sling belay" being replaced by "hanging belay"]

This seems to matter more for big wall climbs, as using a sling belay is considered to be "aid".  To climb such a route "free" requires a longer rope or adjusting the pitches to end at hands-free stances from which to belay.  (This is from a US perspective, those in Europe may take a more relaxed approach to what is allowed for a free ascent.)

Answer (score 2):

A sling belay is typically used to connect 2 points at an anchor.

[image]

[An example belay sling from Edelrid](http://www.outdoor-climbing.de/Edelrid-Belay-Station-Sling-Deluxe_1).

Comment: I would just call that a sling. The question is about a symbol on climbing topos.